# How to get token info with contract address in Ethereum

Tags: web3js, blockchain, tokens, abi, web3-providers

I use web3 library to interact with Ethereum Network and I want to get token info with his contract address such as `tokenName`, `tokenSymbol`, `tokenDecimal`, `tokenLogoURL` etc.
I can get almost any data except for the token logo URL.

Here is the code to get name, symbol, decimal:

```
export async function useGetTokenInfo(chainId: IChainId, tokenAddress: string) {
  const web3: Web3 = new Web3(providers[chainId]);
  const tokenInst = new web3.eth.Contract(tokenABI, tokenAddress);

  const tokenDecimal = await tokenInst.methods.decimals().call();
  const tokenName = await tokenInst.methods.name().call();
  const tokenSymbol = await tokenInst.methods.symbol().call();
}
```

But I have no any idea to get token Logo as url.
Is there any api to get any Ethereum token(For example ERC20, ERC 721 tokens) logo url?

Answer (score 0):

The token logo URL isn't part of the ERC-20 or ERC-721 specifications ([here](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) and [here](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721)). Some tokens may have included it in their contracts, but most of them won't have.

An alternative would be to use the Coingecko API. For example:

> https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/ethereum

Returns a JSON object including the following logo fields:

```
"image": {
    "thumb": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/279/thumb/ethereum.png?1595348880",
    "small": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/279/small/ethereum.png?1595348880",
    "large": "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/279/large/ethereum.png?1595348880"
  },
```

You'll need to replace the `ethereum` query string with the name of the token you're querying. (Which can be found from the list in `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list`.)

This only works for coins and tokens listed on Coingecko. For anything else, you'll have to find another source.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. To clarify again, this api work for tokens and coins both? or just for coins?

Comment: And another alternative solution is that use follow url:
`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/trustwallet/assets/master/blockchains/ethereum/assets/${address}/logo.png`
But it looks does not work for the binance smart chain tokens even though change ethereum with smartchain on the url